# Calculation of growth estimate for a certain transcendental entire function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics

Let $f$ be a transcendental entire function.
Set $$h(z)= z+ f(z)/f'(z)$$ and $$ F(z) = (z-a) f(z)$$.
Then prove that for some $k>0,$ $$T(r, h)\thicksim k T(r, F'/F),$$ where $T$ is the Nevanlinna's characteristics function.

Attempt: $$F'(z)= (z-a)f'(z) + f(z)$$
Then $$F'(z)/F(z)= 1/(z-a) + f'(z)/f(z) = 1/(z-a) + 1/h(z) - z$$
Imples $$T/(r, F'/F) ≤ T(r, 1/z-a) + T(r, 1/h(z)-z) + \log 2$$
I am stuck here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
\frac{F'(z)}{F(z)} = \frac{1}{z-a} + \frac{1}{h(z)-z} \, .
$$
If $F'/F$ and $h$ are both transcendental functions then
$$
T(r, \frac{F'}{F}) \sim T(r, \frac{1}{h-z}) = T(r, h-z) + O(1) \sim T(r,h)
$$
for $r \to \infty$.

Otherwise $F'/F$ and $h$ are both rational functions. Let their respective degrees be $m$ and $n$. Then
$$
T(r, \frac{F'}{F}) \sim m \log(r) \\
T(r, h) \sim n \log(r)
$$
and therefore $ T(r, \frac{F'}{F}) \sim \frac mn T(r, h) $.

Comment: I am wondering why the term $\frac{1}{z-a}$ is neglected and for large $r$, why $T(r, h-z) + O(1) \sim T(r, h)$?

Comment: @Nik: The Nevanlinna characteristic of a transcendental function grows faster than that of any rational function.

Comment: Ok, but what is the logic behind $ T(r, h-z) \sim T(r, h)$ ?

Comment: @Nik: The same, because they differ by a rational function: $T(r, h-z) \le T(r,h) + T(r,z)+O(1) = T(r,h) + O(\log r)$ and vice versa.

Comment: Alright, that is really helpful.